# Ubuntu 16.04.1 keeps randomly freezing on installation

Tags: 16.04, system-installation, usb, freeze

I use windows10 on my ssd.And i bought a harddisk which i want to install ubuntu in it.
I installed Ubuntu **16.04.1 LTS amd64**,and by using "Rufus" i made an image on my 3.0 Usb.I plugged in my usb into an 3.0 port.
-At first it gives me errors and bunch of fails and after that i choose "Install Ubuntu"
-After that it just keeps freezing randomly.
Some people say cut the connection and try it again.I ll do that.

I tried UNetbootin too and it failed too.I dont know why.It gave me an error.And it keeps freezing too.

This is my first time with linux and its a nightmare.Please help me.I do some python programming so i want to use Ubuntu.I want to love linux.

My desktop:
intel 6600k 3.5
gtx 970
GA Z170 HD3P motherboard
16gb ram
64bit

Thank you

Edit:
-I disabled the gpu and tried to install again.Nothing changes,still freezes at -preparing to install ubuntu- So i think the problem isnt about nvidia cards.

I can run ubuntu when i chose "Try ubuntu before install".I click on "install ubuntu" and it freezes at the same spot after i click on 'continue' [freezed installation image.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2d3dj.png)

-For the 'nomodeset' issue,it doesnt give me an option to do it.I mean there is no f6 option or whatever.Just gives me 4 option and i can press e or c.

One time i was installing and it asked me choose the location from the map for the time adjustment.And i couldnt clicked anything.I mean nothing happened,freezed.After that i never saw that page again.The part that i could get so far is the image above which i gave you.

Im struggling with this for days.Now i understand why Windows has the monopoly.But i want to use ubuntu too.So please help me.

Edit2:
-I have dual rams.I took out one and tried again.Still freezes.
-I installed Ubuntu 14 64bit but still freezes.

Comment: Please use this program http://www.pendrivelinux.com/universal-usb-installer-easy-as-1-2-3/ or just burn the ISO to a DVD.

Comment: Thank you so much for the fast tip.I'll try it right away.

Comment: You may need the *nomodeset* option for that GTX970 and you should boot & install in UEFI mode only. Rufus is reliable but you need to select the UEFI/GTP option explicitly. Anyway, prefer tools based on *dd* like MKUSB if you have access to some other Ubuntu machine for a few minutes.

Comment: Also try with the flash drive on a USB2 port, if you have one. @CelticWarrior - Rufus had a "dd mode" I believe, which should work the same way as using `dd` on Linux.

Comment: 1-) I chosed "GPT partition scheme for UEFI" option from rufus.
2-) I cut the internet connection
3-) I didnt enable "Download updates..." and "Third party mp3..." options.
4-)I used 3.0 port first and after that 2.0 and still didnt work.

It always keeps stuck at second page.Where it asks to chose two options(Download updates etc.).
I waited more than 30 minutes and gave up.

I dont know how to set nomodeset option.Im on windows,how do i do that?

Comment: So,no one is going to help me? :(
I had dual ddr4 rams.I took out one of them.Still freezes.I uploaded the moment it freezes.
I dont know what to do.I use windows 10 in my ssd.I play games in it.So i dont think there is a problem in my hardware.But this is so irritating i just cant take it anymore.I have been struggling with this for whole a week! PLEASE!

Comment: You need to press 'e' (edit) with the option selected (Try Ubuntu) and add *nomodeset* after or instead of "quiet splash".

Comment: I believe i tried that.Thank you for the answer anyway.

Comment: I bought a new hard drive.And without any shred of hope i tried to install it again from an usb.It didnt freeze during the installation process.
I dont understand that.Anyway i hope no one will ever experience such an evil problem.